# Applying network latency for every TCP packet

Tags: tcl, ns2

I have a problem to realize various delay in TCP packets. I want to use Gamma distribution like this in tcl file :

```
# Set gamma distribution
set gamma [new RandomVariable/Gamma]
$gamma set alpha_ $alpha
$gamma set beta_ $beta
set gamma2 [$gamma value]
```

How can I use gamma2 value as new delay for each TCP packet? I want to apply this latency before sending the packet like this (but not sure it is correct or not)

```
Agent/TCP instproc mysend {size} {
#change delay
$self change_del
$self send $size
}
```

Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using NS2, so that means you're using the object system [OTcl](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/otcl/doc/tutorial.html) (which is built on top of standard Tcl). To install an override of the `send` method so that you can apply the delay, you need to use *slightly* different syntax. This all assumes that `Agent/TCP` is a subclass of a class that defines `send`…

```
Agent/TCP instproc send {size} {
    # Change the delay
    $self change_del
    # Chain to the superclass implementation
    $self next $size
}
```

The `next` method is rather magical in OTcl; it looks up the caller's superclass implementation and calls that with the arguments provided to it. It's similar (but not identical to) the `super` keyword in Java and the `base` keyword in C#.

---

If `Agent/TCP` is an instance, you use this instead:

```
Agent/TCP proc send {size} {
    # Change the delay
    $self change_del
    # Chain to the superclass implementation
    $self next $size
}
```

That looks almost identical, except now we're using `proc` instead of `instproc`.

Comment: Other object systems in Tcl use a different way to achieve the same thing (`next` isn't a method in either TclOO or XOTcl, both of which can be considered to be somewhat derived from OTcl, but rather a plain command).

Comment: My change_del function is like this, is it right?
Agent/TCP proc change_del {} {
 #change delay of link from agent node to node0
 global ns gamma BS W num_bs_nodes
 #get node where agent resides
 set mynode [$self set node_]
 set new_delay [$gamma value]
 for {set i 0} {$i < [expr $num_bs_nodes] } {incr i} {
 $ns delay $W(0) $BS($i) $new_delay duplex
 }
}